# Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$. Prove that $\frac{a-bc}{a+bc}+\frac{b-ac}{b+ac}+\frac{c-ab}{c+ab}\le \frac32$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$. Prove that $\dfrac{a-bc}{a+bc}+\dfrac{b-ac}{b+ac}+\dfrac{c-ab}{c+ab}\le \dfrac32$.

My attempt:

First I thought if each term could be less than $\dfrac12$. That did not help. So, a little manipulation yielded

$\dfrac{bc}{a+bc}+\dfrac{ca}{b+ca}+\dfrac{ab}{c+ab}\ge \dfrac34$.

Again I thought that each term is greater than $\dfrac14$.

Proceeding that way yielded $3(ab+bc+ca)\ge 1$

Now, $a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca\ge 3(ab+bc+ca)\ge 1$.

Here, we get $1\ge 1$, here, I am confused whether the solution is done or not. I don't think it is. So, please help. Thank you.

Comment: Display environments are not meant for titles.

Comment: I really like your questions about inequalities; there are way to few on MSE. So feel free to ask more :)

Comment: Thanks, I will surely ask when I get stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $a +bc = 1-b-c+bc = (1-b)(1-c)$,

$\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyclic}} (a-bc)(1-a) = \sum a - \sum a^2 - \sum bc + 3abc$

You might need to use Schur inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:$$\left(\dfrac{bc}{a+bc}+\dfrac{ca}{b+ca}+\dfrac{ab}{c+ab}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} bc(a+bc)\right)\ge \left(\sum\limits_{cyc} bc\right)^2$$

So it suffices to prove: $\displaystyle 4\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} bc\right)^2 \ge 3\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} bc(a+bc)\right) = 9abc + 3\sum\limits_{cyc} b^2c^2$

i.e, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc} b^2c^2 + 8abc(a+b+c) \ge 9abc \iff \sum\limits_{cyc} b^2c^2 \ge abc(a+b+c)$ which is just Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your last line.

Comment: @Swadhin $$4\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} bc\right)^2 \\= 4(b^2c^2+c^2a^2+a^2b^2) + 8(ab)(bc)+8(ac)(bc)+8(ab)(ac) \\= 4\sum\limits_{cyc} b^2c^2 + 8abc(a+b+c)$$. 

Using $a+b+c=1$, $b^2c^2+c^2a^2+a^2b^2 \ge (ab)(bc)+(ac)(bc)+(ab)(ac) = abc(a+b+c) = abc$.