# What is the manipulation used to transform $\sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a-bc}{a+bc}$ into $\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{bc}{a+bc}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the inequality shown in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136050/let-a-b-c0-such-that-abc-1-prove-that-fraca-bcabc-fracb-acba?noredirect=1), but I'm confused on how OP concluded that, $$\dfrac{a-bc}{a+bc}+\dfrac{b-ac}{b+ac}+\dfrac{c-ab}{c+ab}\le \dfrac32$$

Implies, $$\dfrac{bc}{a+bc}+\dfrac{ca}{b+ca}+\dfrac{ab}{c+ab}\ge \dfrac34$$.

I tried doing it on my own and only yielded the opposite, $\dfrac{a}{a+bc}+\dfrac{b}{b+ca}+\dfrac{c}{c+ab}\ge \dfrac34$. Any kind of hint is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\frac{a-bc}{a+bc}=\frac{a+bc-2bc}{a+bc}$.

Comment: Note the other equivalent inequality is $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+bc}\leq \frac94$$ so I don't know which process you used to show $\geq \frac34$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a standard technique while proving inequalities, to substitute a fraction with a complementary one in a sense that the sum of these fractions is $1$.

In this case $$\frac{a-bc}{a+bc}= \frac{a+bc-2bc}{a+bc}= \frac{a+bc}{a+bc}- \frac{2bc}{a+bc}=1- \frac{2bc}{a+bc}.$$

So the initial inequality turns into

$$1- \frac{2bc}{a+bc}+1-  \frac{2ac}{b+ac}+1- \frac{2ab}{c+ab}\le\frac32$$

$$- \frac{2bc}{a+bc}-  \frac{2ac}{b+ac}- \frac{2ab}{c+ab}\le-\frac32$$

$$ \frac{2bc}{a+bc}+\frac{2ac}{b+ac}+ \frac{2ab}{c+ab}\ge\frac32$$

$$ \frac{bc}{a+bc}+\frac{ac}{b+ac}+ \frac{ab}{c+ab}\ge\frac34.$$